# Where have the Privacy Settings gone in WordPress 3.5?

Tags: options

I moved a WordPress site to another server and everything is working well, minus the fact that I can't seem to change the settings in Privacy. When I click on "allow search engines to index this site", the radio button automatically switches back to "ask search engines not to index this site". Also, the Privacy Settings menu itself is gone from the Settings menu. I have to manually type in `/wp-admin/options-privacy.php` to access the page. Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *privacy* page was removed in WordPress 3.5. Go to `wp-admin/options-reading.php` and set search engine visibility there.

Answer (score 1):

Is in "Settings > Reading page > Search Engine Visibility".
For more details **[see this blog post](http://haizdesign.com/blog/wordpress/privacy-setting-in-wordpress-3-5/)**.

> If you are developing your WordPress site and don’t want it showing up in search engine results, the WordPress team thoughtfully added a setting for site privacy. You get to decide this when you first install your self-hosted site, but you can change the setting after the fact.